# Leer varias lineas de un archivo de texto en JAVA

Tags: java, archivo

Necesito leer varias lineas de texto de un .txt, después de eso, que aparezcan en pantalla, pero que aparezcan conforme ingrese un salto de linea en terminal.

Lo que hace el programa es que lee las lineas y las imprime luego luego, me gustaria que el usuario pueda decidir cuando pasar a la siguiente palabra al pulsar enter.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Leer {

public void leer () throws IOException {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\SISTEMAS\\Desktop/Palabras.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String texto;
    int i=1;


    while((texto=br.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println(i+" "+texto);
        i++;
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear un Scanner conectado a la entrada estándar y hacer la lectura de la línea dentro del while, eso creará una pausa en el lector del archivo de texto hasta que el usuario presione enter.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Leer {   
    public void leer () throws IOException {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\SISTEMAS\\Desktop/Palabras.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            String texto;
            int i=1;


            while((texto=br.readLine())!=null) {
                System.out.println(i+" "+texto);
                s.nextLine();
                i++;
            }

        }
}
```